# Vue.js и переменные экземпляра

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            authors: [],
            error: '',
            bookName: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAuthors(){
            this.$http.get('/api/getAuthors').then((response) => {
                response.body.error ? this.error = response.body.error : this.authors = response.body;
            });
            console.log('Success.');
        },
        clicked(){
            console.log(this.authors);
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getAuthors()
        console.log('Component created.')

    },


}
```

Когда пытаюсь вывести this.authors функцией clicked() выводится undefined.

getAuthors:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Если выведу console.log(response.body) -> выведет объекты корректно. Поэтому думаю в сторону области видимости функции.

Comment: выведи `this` внутри clicked, и посмотри на что он указывает

Comment: Пустой объект authors, http://prntscr.com/gelmdl, а так компонент vue остается

Comment: Попробуйте для начала оставить только  this.authors = response.body, без условия.